# code name one text area cursor position shows in next line in i pad device?

Tags: position, cursor, textarea, codenameone

I placed the text area in my application when i click on text area the cursor position is starting from next line  in ipad device, after entered the string and click on done button it navigates to first line.

please find the below code,

```
String savedComments = roasterDao.getComments();
commentText = new TextArea(savedComments);
commentText.setEditable(true);
commentText.setFocusable(true);
commentText.setMaxSize(1000);
textContainer = new Container();
textContainer.add(commentText);
```

Please find the below images ,

[image: Please find the below image 1 related cursor position start in next line]

[image: Please find the below image 2 related cursor position navigates to first line]

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no cursor in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the cursor is in the next line because `savedComments` has a newline in it. It's hard to tell what happened here but I'm guessing you have two separate UIID styles for selected/unselected with different padding/margin values that result in a difference in appearance when you start editing.

Notice we have an iPad skin in the simulator that you can try to use to reproduce some device issues although editing is a bit different on devices...

Comment: if savedComments has a newline,then in android device also the cursor position shows in next line right? but it shows in first line only and i am applying the same UIID styles for selected/unselected.

Comment: The same UIID but does that UIID override padding/margin in one of the styles and not in the other. Make sure it uses millimeter padding/margin in both.

Comment: yes. It uses the millimeter for padding/margin in both.

Comment: Can you clarify the issue with a device screenshot that shows the keyboard/cursor? I'm not sure I follow the issue

Comment: Your description mentions a cursor and keyboard none of which appear in the screenshots. I'm looking at the screenshots and maybe I'm missing something obvious but I don't see anything wrong with them?